# SQL Replace some text of each string of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that contains a column named: "shortLink".
This column contains a short link of an address of each row in the table.
I use the tinyurl.com services for the short links. The short link looks like this: `https://tinyurl .com/randomletters`.

Recently I figured out that I need to change the shortlinks to their preview short link version: `https://preview.tinyurl .com/randomletters`.

The only difference between the two link formats is that there is a prefix `preview.` between `https://` and `tinyurl`.

Since I have hundreds of rows in the sql table I cannot fix this manually.
Is there any way to convert each shortlink (by adding the prefix `preview.` in the address) to its preview format with code in sql?

Thanks.

PS - Notice that there is a gap between `tinyurl`  and `.com` in the link formats above. This gap is added intentionally because the forum would not let me publish the question otherwise.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- this will update the field for you where it does not already have the preview. in it.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET  shortlinks= REPLACE( shortlinks, 'https://tinyurl .com', 'https://preview.tinyurl .com')
WHERE  shortlinks NOT LIKE 'https://preview.tinyurl%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `update`:

```
update t
    set shortlink = concat('http://preview.', substring(shortlink, 8))
    where shorlink like 'http://tinyurl%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro try this. first, remove all spaces in URL on anywhere then replace 'tinyurl' to 
'preview'

```
UPDATE [Table_Name]
SET  shortLink=  REPLACE(REPLACE( shortLink, ' ', ''),'tinyurl', 'preview')
```